# Is there any way to find relationship/correlation between columns with one row data or two?

Tags: python

So what I'm trying to figure out is, if I have demographic data where we have an average age column (e.g. 41 and 42) for each city, and their values of course vary.

It's only two row-values because the data is from every 10th year.

Thus my question is, whether there is anything to say about their relationship between with regards to the Y-axis (Demand of certain product) or solely only the column of average age between different cities?